# I'd like the sidebar menu to show as a default on the mobile phone

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, sidebar

I have a bootstrap responsive site. When I open it on the PC, the sidebar menu shows, which is exactly what I want. When I open the site on the iPhone the sidebar menu does not show as a default. When I press the Toggle Menu button it then displays. How can I change my code to make the **sidebar menu show** on the iPhone as a default without my having to press the Toggle Menu button? Thank you.

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Sales Enablement</title>

    <!-- Our own local CSS -->
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="index.html">
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a href="theBoldPitch.html">The Bold Pitch</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link 6</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link 7</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>

                        <h1>Make the Pitch Bold</h1>
                        <p>When making the sales pitch, challenge and go big.</p>

                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                              <!--only use last part of the youtube video link-->
                            <iframe style="border: 1px solid #000;" class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/RPmTA6O97Y4" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a full working example. Also, why do you include `jQuery` and `Bootstrap` twice?

Comment: I did not even notice that I had them listed twice. I just commented out the duplications. Thank you. Also, this is a full working example. The code that I listed gives me a full page with a sidebar menu and a video to play.

Comment: You need to post your CSS for a **minimal working example**: [mcve]

Comment: I edited my code and included the CSS code as suggested.

Comment: @JohnM, please use the snippet tool (`<>` button) and link all required assets until it works. All your assets, except one, have relative paths. Therefore are not loading here. Please use absolute paths. Make your example work here, in the snippet.